# Привязка к TabControl.SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Нужно сделать чтобы кнопка была видна только если в TabControl выбран элемент с индексом 1. Пытаюсь сделать через конвертер, но не работает.

```
                    <Button.Visibility>
                        <Binding ElementName="mainTab" 
                                 Converter="{StaticResource BackButtonVisibleConverter}"
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            </Binding>
                    </Button.Visibility>
```

Converter

```
public class BackButtonVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            TabControl tab = value as TabControl;
            if (tab.SelectedIndex == 1)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: return Visibility.Visible; **ELSE** 
            return Visibility.Hidden;

Comment: @МаксимКутовой, зачем здесь else? Если отработает первый return, до второго уже не дойдем.

Comment: а в ресурсах XAML вы создаете `BackButtonVisibleConverter`?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик да, создаю. Конвертер отрабатывает только один раз почему-то, при смене TabControl.SelectedIndex он уже не отрабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так, сори поправил.

```
<Button.Visibility>
  <Binding ElementName="mainTab" 
           Path="SelectedIndex"
           UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
    <Binding.Converter>
      <local:BackButtonVisibleConverter/>
    </Binding.Converter>
  </Binding>
</Button.Visibility>
```

и в конвертере используйте SelectedIndex

```
if (1.Equals(value))
  return Visibility.Visible;
```

дело в том, что `PropertyChanged` не сработает, т.к. сам `mainTab` не меняется, но если вы укажете именно свойство `SelectedIndex` в `Path`, то `PropertyChanged` для `Path` отработает

Comment: Действительно, не подумал об этом. Ваше решение помогло, спасибо.